# Using tabularx to create custom section headers

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, tabularx

Like many LaTeX users, I spend too much time tinkering around rather than writing the actual document. But I am wondering if anyone has attempted this or not.

I've been working on getting the first cell in a table to read as `\section{"my section name"}` that can be read by `\tableofcontents`. For reference, I am using Rstudio (v0.99.467) with Sweave,knitr,xelatex, etc. to write white papers with ggplots.

Currently, I am manually creating section headings (without `\section`; see below), but it would helpful to write each using `\section` as my documents are increasing in length. I've tried inserting `\section` in various locations in the tabularx block (see code below), but I am unable to get it to read. There doesn't seem to be much information on this. I'll try to explain this in a little more detail.

First, I've posted a few screenshots.

### Example of Custom Format for Section Headings

#### Screenshot - Actual

Here's what the final output looks like.

[image]

#### Screenshot - Structure

To demonstrate the structure, here's is what section header looks like with all of of the borders turned on (recreated in pages).
[image]

#### Current Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{} }
    \multirow{2}{*}{\fontsize{15}{10}\selectfont My First Section} & \\
    \cline{2-2}
    & \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

#### Other tests:

Insert `\section` before name

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{} }
    \multirow{2}{*}{\fontsize{15}{10}\selectfont \section{My First Section}} & \\
    \cline{2-2}
    & \\
\end{tabularx}
```

Insert `\section` before `\fontsize`

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{} }
    \multirow{2}{*}{\section{{\fontsize{15}{10}\selectfont My First Section}}} & \\
    \cline{2-2}
    & \\
\end{tabularx}
```

I've tested the `\sectionfont{}` command, but could not get it to work. Would anyone have any suggestions? I'm wondering if this may be an issue with specifying too many things (tabularx, multirow, setting manual fontsize, borders, etc.).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is the good way.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,multirow,sectsty}

\sectionfont{\fontsize{15}{10}\selectfont\sectabx}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{15}{10}\selectfont\subsectabx}

\newcommand{\sectabx}[1]{%
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{} }
    \multirow{2}{*}{#1} & \\
    \cline{2-2}
    & \\
\end{tabularx}}

\newcommand{\subsectabx}[1]{%
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{} l| X @{}| }
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{#1} & \\
    \cline{2-2}
    & \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}}

\begin{document}

\section{My First Section}
bla bla
\subsection{My First subSection}
bla bla

\section*{My First Section}
bla bla
\subsection*{My First subSection}
bla bla

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is absolutely perfect! Thanks for your help.